# Which is faster in mysql string search or combination of the integer with a join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

A table has column as category_NAME/ID where we can pass either id and create another table for list of that category or directly add the category name.

Which one is fater

**CASE 1:**

**TABLE1**

```
ID | CATEGORY_NAME
```

**CASE 2**

here to fetch list we have make one `JOIN` statement

**TABLE1**

```
ID | CATEGORY_ID
```

**CATEGORY_TABLE**

```
ID | CATEGORY NAME
```

Comment: What were the results of your testing? You need to consider how maintainable the database and associated code is too, for example, how much hassle would it be if the category name was changed?

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference between 
**CASE 1:
TABLE1**

```
ID | CATEGORY_NAME
```

**CASE 2**

here to fetch list we have make one JOIN statement

**TABLE1**

```
ID | CATEGORY_ID
```

**CATEGORY_TABLE**

```
ID | CATEGORY NAME
```

I suppose what you mean by first case is Item_id.

In that case it depends on code maintainability and storage. As if category name is changed, you have to update the record in your large table,that will be heavy query.
Also as you are storing category_id instead of its name,it will help in saving storage space.As you are not replicating category name for each record but just refering to category_id.

But clearly it depends on the size of category and size of items.

Answer (score 1):

If **TABLE1** size is rather small (let's say less than 10k rows at max), indexed **VARCHAR CATEGORY_NAME** should work OK, otherwise better to use a separate table for storing categories.

Personally, I would go with option 2. Performance improvement here will not be so dramatically, but storing dictionary field inside another table is a bad practice.